# How i can use plugin vars october cms in func 'onStart'

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms, octobercms-plugins

I have plugin user in October cms. I can use `{{user.name}}` in page, but how i can use it on function onStart

Comment: show us your code so we can help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Auth:: fascade

```
$user = Auth::getUser();
```